# Django: restricting possible dates

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django. I am using Django 1.8 and Python 3.4.

```
class Card(models.Model):
    STATUS_EXPIRED = "EX"
    STATUS_ACTIVE = "AC"
    STATUS_DEACTIVATED = "DE"
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
         (STATUS_ACTIVE, "Active"),
         (STATUS_EXPIRED, "Expired"),
         (STATUS_DEACTIVATED, "Deactivated")
    )

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    series = models.CharField(verbose_name="Series", max_length=8, null=False, blank=False)
    number = models.CharField(verbose_name="Number", max_length=16, null=False, blank=False)
    issue_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Issue Date", auto_now=True, null=False, blank=False)
    expire_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Expiry Date", auto_now=False, null=False, blank=False)
    status = models.CharField(verbose_name="Status", max_length=3, null=False, blank=False, default="AC")
```

How do I ensure that `expire_date` is never less than `issue_date` in the database? How do I enforce this condition in Django-admin interface when creating objects of `Card` class?

Answer (score 3):

You can do a form validation in admin like this;

```
from models import Card
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms


class CardForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Card
        fields = ('series', 'number', 'issue_date', 'expire_date', 'status')

    def clean(self):
        issue_date = self.cleaned_data.get('issue_date')
        expire_date = self.cleaned_data.get('expire_date')
        if expire_date < issue_date:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Wrong dates")
    return self.cleaned_data


class CardAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CardForm
    list_display = ('series', 'number', 'issue_date', 'expire_date', 'status')

admin.site.register(Card, CardAdmin)
```

Comment: Hi Geo/Jacob (I'd like to address you by first name, but I don't know which it is – apologies!). 

Thank you for your help. I would like to note that in Django 1.8, this does not work without additionally setting the `fields` member in `Meta`, so please consider updating your answer.

Comment: Um. I am not sure. I have just used '\_\_all\_\_', but I presume it should accept a tuple of the fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom model form ( [Model forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/) ) and validate the data before saving and while registering do something like

```
class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ModelForm
    list_display = ('field1', 'field2')

admin.site.register(Lecture, LectureAdmin)
```